# Não funciona ao apertar determinada sequencia de botoes, com js e html

Tags: javascript, html

Bom dia galera da stack overflow.
Eu estou passando por um problema estranho, nem sei como o descrever.

Basicamente tenho as 2 telas a baixo
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu estou criando um form, onde vai ser necessário cadastrar e editar no mesmo.
Então minha ideia foi criar 3 botões, um para editar, ou para cadastrar e outro para cancelar.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
        <a href="javascript:;" id="EdicaoLocalidade" class="btn green EditarLocalidade">Editar Localidade</a>
        <a href="javascript:;" id="CadastrarLocalidade" class="btn green CadastrarLocalidade">Cadastrar Localidade</a>
        <a href="javascript:;" class="btn default Cancelar">Cancelar</a>                            </div>
```

A ideia é, quando apertar o botão Nova Localidade, é fazer com que o botão Editar desaparecesse, assim ficando apenas o Cadastrar e Cancelar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
$('.page-toolbar a').click(function() {
            inicNovaLocalidade();
            $('.portlet.NovaLocalidade').slideDown();
            $(this).addClass('disabled');
            $(".EditarLocalidade").css("display","none");

        });
```

A mesma ideia seria para o editar, quando clica na caneta, ao lado dos dados, ou seja, para editar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
$(".Editar").on('click', function () {
            $('.portlet.NovaLocalidade').slideDown();
            $(".CadastrarLocalidade").css("display","none");

        })
```

O problema bizarro, é quando eu aperto primeiro o Editar, o botão cancelar não funciona de jeito nenhum, porém se eu aperto o Nova Localidade, o cancelar, funciona certinho, para ambos os casos.

A minha ideia, é que quando apertasse o cancelar, alem de dar o slide down, ia desfazer o efeito de oculto do botão.

```
//evento click do cancelar
$('#CadastroLocalidade a.Cancelar').click(function() {
    //teste para o botão cadastrar localidade
    var editLocalidade = document.getElementById("EdicaoLocalidade");
    var cadLocalidade = document.getElementById("CadastrarLocalidade");

    if(editLocalidade.style.display != 'none'){
        $('.portlet.NovaLocalidade').slideUp();
        $('.page-toolbar a').removeClass('disabled');
        $(".EditarLocalidade").css("display","inline-block");
    }


});
```

**ATUALIZANDO**

Quando clico nesse botão aqui, que o cancelar não funciona... de forma alguma, esse o erro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que você deseja fazer é isso? https://jsfiddle.net/mapquintal/fwx9qw1y/

Comment: Não, preciso que quando clique naquela seta do editar, funcione o cancelar por exemplo... e não estou entendo o motivo que não funciona

Comment: tá chamando $(".Editar").on('click', function () {
em vez de $(".EditarLocalidade").on('click', function () {

Comment: Mas isso ta certo, só o cancelar que não funciona, quando clico no botão para Editar

Comment: Não consigo entender o erro

Comment: Editei a pergunta

Answer (score 0):

Nessa Função, ao clicar em cadastrar é realizado um `hide` no botão de editar e vice-versa. Clicando em cancelar, é exibido novamente todos os botões.

```js
$("#operacao").on('click','a', function () {
    if($(this).attr("id") == "editar"){
        $("#cadastrar").hide();
        $("#editar").show();
    }else if($(this).attr("id") == "cadastrar"){
     $("#cadastrar").show();
        $("#editar").hide();
    }else{
     $("#cadastrar").show();
        $("#editar").show();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="operacao">
    <a href="#?" id="editar">Editar</a>
    </br>
    <a href="#?" id="cadastrar">Cadastrar</a>
    </br>
    <a href="#?" id="cancelar">Cancelar</a> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#CadastroLocalidade a.Cancelar').click(function() {
```

O ID do elemento está errado #CadastroLocalidade deveria ser #Cadastra**r**Localidade

Comment: Com o cadastrar funciona, isso que não entendo

Comment: @Gabrielfalieri pq 'CadastroLocalidade' não existe como id de um elemento.

Comment: O nome está errado, mude CadastroLocalidade para CadastrarLocalidade

Está faltando o R do Cadastra'R'

Comment: what?? Vocês entenderam o que está acontecendo?

Comment: Sim @Gabrielfalieri, entendi, você disse que o botão do cancelar não funciona....
Justamente porque a chamada do botão em jQuery está chamando um botão que não existe, o ID do elemento está errado, por isso o botão não executa.

Comment: Se o código que você possui aí no desenvolvimento for o mesmo que você postou aqui, acredito que seja esse o problema. Tente mudar e teste.  =D

Comment: Olha, quando eu clico no Nova Localidade, o mesmo cancelar funciona, ele usa a mesma referencia.
Quando eu uso aquele botãozinho, que mencionei lá em cima, não funciona... e teoricamente era para funciona, porque faz a chamada para o mesmo lugar

Comment: É só botões diferentes, porém a chamada do cancelar é a mesma, quando aperto em nova localidade funciona primeiro... o cancelar funciona em ambos os casos, só quando eu clico em editar primeiro

Comment: Então cara... sacou o que está acontecendo?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52470/discussion-between-gabriel-falieri-and-gilberto-b-terra-jr).